Next.js App: Dynamic Metadata Changes Not Reflecting After Deployment
I have a Next.js application deployed to Firebase. The app fetches metadata (title and description) from a Firestore database using generateMetadata in the root layout. Here's the relevant code:
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import "./globals.css";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@/components/ui/theme-provider";
import { AppProvider } from "@/context/AppContext";
import { Toaster } from "@/components/ui/toaster";
import { db } from "./firebase";

export async function generateMetadata() {
  const id = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COMPANY_ID;

  try {
    
    // Fetch assistant data from Firestore based on the ID
    const metadataDocRef = doc(db, "domains", id);
    const metadataDoc = await getDoc(metadataDocRef);
    const assistantData = metadataDoc.data();

    // Extract the title and description
    const metaTitle =
      assistantData?.configuration?.metaTitle || "AI Assistant | KreateBots";
    const metaDescription =
      assistantData?.configuration?.metaDescription ||
      "Your personal AI Assistant, powered by KreateBots";

    return {
      title: metaTitle,
      description: metaDescription,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching metadata:", error);
    return {
      title: "Default Title",
      description: "Default Description",
    };
  }
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning>
      <head>
        <link
          rel="icon"
          href="https://storage.googleapis.com/json_articles/dataknobs-logo-2.jpg"
        />
      </head>
      <body className={`antialiased`}>
        <ThemeProvider
          attribute="class"
          defaultTheme="system"
          enableSystem
          disableTransitionOnChange
        />
        <main>
          <AppProvider>
            {children}
            <Toaster />
          </AppProvider>
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

When I deploy the app, it shows the metadata stored in Firestore at the time of deployment. However, if I update the metadata in Firestore after deployment, the changes do not reflect on the deployed site unless I redeploy the app.
How can I make the metadata update dynamically based on Firestore changes?
Help me get through this
